# Is it possible to shorten call line by merging classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing view class for data and I will invoke multiple methods in data class, so I want to shorten call line by removing name of data class and only writing methods and field like they're part of view class.

```cs
public class Data
{
  public int field1;
  public string field2;

  public void ClearData()
  {
    field1 = 0;
    field2 = "";
  }
}

public class Main
{
  public void Foo(){
    var data = DataLoader.LoadData(); // load data from somewhere else
    using (data) // this is not working in c#, I've written using because I want it to be working like this
    {
      Console.WriteLine(field1.ToString()); // Acces to data.field1 by writing only field1 because this codeline is inside using (data) zone
      Console.WriteLine(field2); // Acces to data.field2 by writing only field2 because this codeline is inside using (data) zone
      ClearData(); // Acces to data.ClearData method by writing only ClearData() because this codeline is inside using (data) zone
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write something like it in c#? (c# 7.3)

P.S. I know that it's poor code that is hard to understand, but I want to know is it possible to do so.

Comment: No it isn't. You can only do that for `static` methods/field by using [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) .. but that doesn't seem to be what you are after ...

Comment: Also note that the [`using` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) is only used as a "secure" wrapper around instances of an [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) type .. It was probably just an example, I know, but just to be sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this

```
field1.ToString()
```

the compiler has no way of knowing what "field1", "field2", etc are without specifying the object they live in.

```
using (data)
```

doesn't work like it does in some other languages where it says "use this object for all field references" and the compiler works it out from there.

you would write something like

```
using (var data = DataLoader.LoadData())
{
  Console.WriteLine(data.field1.ToString()); 
  Console.WriteLine(data.field2); 
  ClearData(); **<<< nothing like this exists**
}
```